# Flutter Notification pending intent canceled when clicked on FCM notification

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

when I get a notification from `firebase_messaging` while the application is in the background when I click it logs this error in the console `Notification pending intent canceled` instead of opening the app. and nothing happens

please note that am using `flutter 1.22..6` for this project so I had to use an old version of `firebase_messageing` which is `7.0.3`

I have those lines in my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```xml
<!-- Note i have changed MainActitvy to Application based on documutions -->
    <application
        android:name=".Application" 
        android:label="DR Vendor"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
       ....

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
       .....
    </application>
```

And I have **Application.java** to be like :

```java
package Here I have my package name;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
    }

}
```

And added this file in the same folder **FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.java**:

```java
package my bundle name here;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;

public final class FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant {
    public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
            return;
        }
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }

    private static boolean alreadyRegisteredWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        final String key = FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.class.getCanonicalName();
        if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
            return true;
        }
        registry.registrarFor(key);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is how I added my background handler method as a static top-level method

**main.dart**

```dart
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
  }

  if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
    // Handle notification message
    final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
    print("got notification");
    print(message);
  }
  print("reached here");
  // Or do other work.
}



Future<void> main() async {
....
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  PushNotificationsManager().init();
...
```

And this is how i initalize FCM when i called the line `PushNotificationsManager().init();` in `main.dart`

```dart
  Future<void> init() async {
    if (!_initialized) {
      // For iOS request permission first.
      _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
      _firebaseMessaging.configure();
      var initializationSettingsAndroid =
      new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/launcher_icon');
      var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
      var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
          android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);

      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
          onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
      configureNotifications();

      // For testing purposes print the Firebase Messaging token
      String token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      print("FirebaseMessaging token: $token");

      _initialized = true;
    }
  }
  configureNotifications() {
    final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        _showNotification(
            1234,
            "${message['notification']['title']}",
            "${message['notification']['body']}",
            "${message['data']['order_id']}");
        return;
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        return;
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        onSelectNotification("${message['data']['order_id']}");
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is in the initialization in the main

```
PushNotificationsManager().init();
```

to

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

and use this code for opened a activity or screen.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/message',
          arguments: MessageArguments(message, true));
    });
```

thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help but this version of `7.0.3` of `firebase_messaging` doesn't have the `onMessageOpenedApp` function so am handling it using `onLaunch:(Map<String,dynamic> message){}` inside `FirebaseMEssaging.configure()` as mentioned in the officeal docs `https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/versions/7.0.3`, also i already have `await Firebase.initializeApp();` just forgot to mention , updating question

Comment: use that `void _navigateToItemDetail(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    final Item item = _itemForMessage(message);
    Navigator.popUntil(context, (Route<dynamic> route) => route is PageRoute);
    if (!item.route.isCurrent) {
      Navigator.push(context, item.route);
    }
  }` and in on Launch this : `_navigateToItemDetail(message);`